# Drawing Alphabets / Text animation iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, animation, draw

Well i am trying to make a Kids Tracing application on iOS. 
I am facing problems in implementing animation of drawing Alphabets. The application will draw the Alphabets to demonstrate how it should be traced.

how to implement this?

I found some code:  https://github.com/ole/Animated-Paths
But here the Alphabets are being mapped in two paths(inner body and outer body)

I want to implement this in a single path. i tried to edit the code but failed

Can anyone guide me how to do it?

thank you

Comment: i got the same problem with that one path only for one alphabets, did you solved it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use FloodFill algorithm , This will help you for tracing

Answer (score 0):

I been also scratching my head to implement same thing in which I can draw an alphabet on the so that the touches to an alphabet can be recognised.

Here is a bit of logic I used,

- Get the letter (Alphabet).  1
- Get the Glyph of the alphabet.  2
- Create a path for glyph.  3
- Render a path from glyph to bezier path. 4
- Draw a bezier on view. 5
- Get points on bezier. 6
- Once, touch search them on in bezier point of they belong to our. 7

---

path.

Here is code sample for the same.

```
//Get the glyph
const char charater = "A";    //1:
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:100.0];
CTFontRef cgFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)font.fontName, 100.0, nil);
CFStringRef str = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, &charater, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
CGGlyph glyph = CTFontGetGlyphWithName(cgFont, str);  //2:

// render the glyph into a bezier path
CGPathRef path = CTFontCreatePathForGlyph(cgFont, glyph, nil); //3:
UIBezierPath *BPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:path];
BPath = BPath.bezierPathByReversingPath;
NSLog(@"Path is %@", BPath); //4:
CAShapeLayer *line = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
line.path = BPath.CGPath;
line.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
line.fillColor = [[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:img2] CGColor];
[myView.layer addSublayer:line];  //5:

//Get the points on path

CGPathRef yourCGPath = BPath.CGPath;
NSMutableArray *bezierPoints = [NSMutableArray array];
CGPathApply(yourCGPath, (__bridge void * _Nullable)(bezierPoints), MyCGPathApplierFunc);
NSLog(@"Points on path %@", bezierPoints); //6:


//Check if point present on path
CGPoint StartPoint1 = [Touch locationInView:myView];
if(CGRectContainsPoint(myView.frame, StartPoint1)){
//Do your work.   //7:
}


//GetPoints

void MyCGPathApplierFunc (void *info, const CGPathElement *element) {
NSMutableArray *bezierPoints = (__bridge NSMutableArray *)info;
CGPoint *points = element->points;
CGPathElementType type = element->type;
switch(type) {
        case kCGPathElementMoveToPoint: // contains 1 point
            [bezierPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:points[0]]];
            break;

        case kCGPathElementAddLineToPoint: // contains 1 point
            [bezierPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:points[0]]];
            break;

        case kCGPathElementAddQuadCurveToPoint: // contains 2 points
            [bezierPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:points[0]]];
            [bezierPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:points[1]]];
            break;

        case kCGPathElementAddCurveToPoint: // contains 3 points
            [bezierPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:points[0]]];
            [bezierPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:points[1]]];
            [bezierPoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:points[2]]];
            break;

        case kCGPathElementCloseSubpath: // contains no point
            break;
    }
}
```